# WPF Nested User Controls Dependency Binding Properties

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, prism

I have an WPF application using Prism using ViewModels and I'm having problems with a Nested UserControl with its own CodeBehind and DependencyBinding properties.

With this code the binding in PanZoomControl is not working, the image is not set and in debugging the `get` and `set` are not called.

ImagePreviewView.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="Modules.ImagePreviewView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
         xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:UI.Infrastructure.Controls;assembly=UI.Infrastructure"
         prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True">
<x:Code>
    <![CDATA[ public ImagePreviewView() { InitializeComponent(); } ]]>
</x:Code>

<Grid>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <controls:PanZoomControl Grid.RowSpan="3"
                             Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
                             ImageSrc="{Binding ImagePreviewVM.ImagePreview}">
    </controls:PanZoomControl>

</Grid>
```

PanZoomControl.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="UI.Infrastructure.Controls.PanZoomControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <Image Source="{Binding ImageSrc}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

PanZoomControl.xaml.cs

```
public partial class PanZoomControl : UserControl
{
    #region Dependency Properties
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageSourceProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("ImageSrc", typeof(object), typeof(PanZoomControl));

    public object ImageSrc
    {
        get { return GetValue(ImageSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value); }
    }
    
    #endregion

    public PanZoomControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ImageSrc` is not a property of DataContext, it is a property of control itself, so change binding source:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UI.Infrastructure.Controls.PanZoomControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             Name="uc"
             mc:Ignorable="d"  
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <Image Source="{Binding ImageSrc, ElementName=uc}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

also since DP is registered with name `ImageSrc`, then it should be named `ImageSrcProperty`

Comment: I have tryed this and that works for me! Thanks for your reply